# Converting an implicit 3-variable equation into explicit function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

I have the equation:
$$xz(y+1)+e^y=1$$
and I would like to be able to write $y$ as a function of $x$ and $z$ i.e. $y=f(x,z)$.
How would I go about this? I think this might have something to do with partial derivatives.
Eventually, I want to determine:

$$\lim_{(x,z)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,z)}{x^2+z^2}$$

Alternatively, how do I compute this limit if I can't find a formula for $y=f(x,z)$ ?

Comment: I'm guessing writing $y=f(x,z)$ isn't your ultimate goal. It's probably best you mention what exactly you want to achieve because you might be taking a longer path which might even not have and end.

Comment: You do not need to find an explicit equation to do implicit differentiation, in case you are confused.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is merely a step towards my ultimate goal, if it is possible. If not, any ideas on how I could find the limit?

Comment: If $xz$ is negative, it looks like there could be two solutions for $y$. If so, which solution do you want? Or are you assuming $xz \geq 0$?

Comment: I'm not sure I want solutions to the equation, but rather to eventually find the limit I mentioned.

Comment: The limit may depend on which solution for $y$ you take (or it may not, it depends on the particular problem)

Comment: but doesn't the limit only depend on the values of x and z (and f(x,z))? Or am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Sure, but $f(x,z)$ may have two different possible values if $xz < 0$. So then the question is whether your limit can change if you pick a different value for $f(x,z)$.  It's possible that you get the same limit no matter which of the possible values you choose for $f(x,z)$

Comment: I don't have any extra information or restrictions so I assume that I will need the value of the limit for each possible circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

The point $(0,0,0)$ satisfies the given equation
$$F(x,y,z):=xz(y+1)+e^y-1=0,\ \tag{1}$$ and I take it that you are interested in the function $$f:\ (x,z)\mapsto y=f(x,z)$$
defined in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, satisfying $f(0,0)=0$ and $F\bigl(x,f(x,z),z\bigr)\equiv0$.

For the moment we put $xz=:u$; then $(1)$ will be replaced by
$$G(u,y):=u(y+1)+e^y-1=0\ .\tag{2}$$
Now $(0,0)$ is a solution of $(2)$; furthermore
$$G_u(0,0)=1,\quad G_y(0,0)=1\ne0\ .$$
It follows that $(2)$ defines in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$ a $C^1$-function $y=\phi(u)$ with $\phi(0)=0$ and
$$\phi'(0)=-{G_u(0,0)\over G_y(0,0)}=-1\ .$$
Therefore
$$y=-u+o(|u|)\qquad(u\to0)\ ,$$
and returning to $x$ and $z$ we have
$$f(x,z)=-xz+o(|xz|)\qquad\bigl((x,z)\to(0,0)\bigr)\ .$$
As $|xz|\leq {1\over2}(x^2+z^2)$ it follows that
$${f(x,z)\over x^2+z^2}=-{x z\over x^2+z^2}+o(1)\qquad\bigl((x,z)\to(0,0)\bigr)\ .$$
From this we conclude that the limit in question does not exist: Approaching $(0,0)$ horizontally we get the limit $0$, and approaching $(0,0)$ from north-west we get the limit $-{1\over2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using implicit derivation you can compute the Taylor aproximation of $y$ around $(0,0)$.

$y(0,0)=0$,

$$
y_x=\frac{-z(y+1)}{e^y+xz} \;\; y_z=\frac{-x(y+1)}{e^y+xz}
$$
So 
 $y_x(0,0)=0$, $y_z(0,0)=0$.

You can also compute the second derivatives (Verify, I did not do the calculations carefully):
$$
y_{xx}(0,0)=0 \;\; y_{xz}(0,0)=-1\;\; y_{zz}(0,0)=0
$$ 
Therefore 
$$
y(x,z)=-\frac{zx}{2}+ O(\left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\right)^3)
$$
and then
$$
\lim_{(x,z)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{y(x,z)}{x^2+z^2} \mbox{ does not exist.}
$$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think this is close to what I am looking for. I can do the implicit differentiation and I am fine with the second order partial derivatives. What does the function for $y(x,z)$ you have given mean? I understand the the first few terms of the taylor series all add to 0, but what does your second term mean and, if not obvious from that answer, how did you find it? Is it some sort of collection of all the non-computed terms? How do you deal with it in the limit? It seems to approach 0...because it's some sort of function of x and z?

Comment: $y(W)=P_k(W)+ R_{k+1}(W)$ where $P_k$ is the Taylor polynomial and $R_{k+1}$ is the residual. The residual is of order $k+1$. That in particular implies $R_{k+1}(W)/||W||^{k} \rightarrow 0$. The usual notation for this is $R_{k+1}=o(||W||^k)$ or $R_{k+1}=O(||W||^{k+1})$. See big O notation.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections made and apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Your English is fine! Thank you for explaining things to me. So we have something like $\lim_{(x,z)\to (0,0)} \frac{(x^2+z^2)^(3/2)}{x^2+z^2} = \lim_{(x,z)\to(0,0)} sqrt{x^2+z^2} = 0$ ? One more question though: How do we know what the residual looks like? I understand where the power of 3 comes from, but where does the $sqrt(x^2+z^2)$ come from?

Comment: Your English is fine! Thank you for explaining things to me. So we have something like $\lim_{(x,z)\to (0,0)} \frac{(x^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{x^2+z^2} = \lim_{(x,z)\to(0,0)} \sqrt{x^2+z^2} = 0$ ? One more question though: How do we know what the residual looks like? I understand where the power of 3 comes from, but where does the $\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ come from?

Comment: Never mind. I answered my own question! Thanks again

Comment: Note there was a´mistake  in my calculus.  It was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If $xz \to 0^-$ (i.e. $xz$ is always negative approaching $0$), then you can find a large negative solution for $y$ such that $xz(y+1)$ is approximately $1$ (slightly less) and $e^y$ is almost $0$ (slightly more). Then your limit of $f(x,z)/(x^2 + z^2)$ for this solution for $y = f(x,z)$ would be $- \infty$ as $(x,z) \to 0$ along trajectories such that $xz \to 0^-$.  Of course, this solution for $xz < 0$ cannot be extended to a continuous or smooth solution $f(x,z)$ because you must have $f(0,0) = 0$. So maybe you can avoid this gotcha by insisting that $f$ is continuous/differentiable, and then $f$ could potentially be uniquely defined to be a nice solution for which a limit exists.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Thinking about it, can we claim that $y=f(x,z)$ must be continuous/differentiable, by the implicit function theorem (at least in the neighbourhood of $(0,0)$)?